# How to use lifecycleObserver for ON_CREATE before the method is called

Tags: android, realm, android-lifecycle

I use RealmDB and per the documentations, the best practice is to get an instance of the DB on "onCreate" methods and clear it on "onDestroy", so far so good - I've done that.

Since we have multiple schemas for various data objects, I want to make my code cleaner by using something like this:

```
interface RealmOwner : RealmOwnerBase {
    val realmContainer: BaseRealmContainer

    override val configurationA: Realm
        get() = realmContainer.configurationA
    override val configurationB: Realm
        get() = realmContainer.configurationB

    abstract class BaseRealmContainer {
        lateinit var configurationA: Realm
        lateinit var configurationB: Realm
    }

    open class RealmContainer
        : BaseRealmContainer() {

        open fun initRealm() {
            configurationA = RealmFactory.configurationA
            configurationB = RealmFactory.configurationB
        }

        open fun closeRealm() {
            listOf(configurationA, configurationB).forEach { it.close() }
        }
    }

    class LifecycleRealmContainer(lifecycle: Lifecycle)
        : RealmContainer(), LifecycleObserver {

        init {
            lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
        override fun initRealm() {
            super.initRealm()
        }

        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        override fun closeRealm() {
            super.closeRealm()
        }
    }
}
```

Activities and fragments can inherit from "RealmOwner", and implement the mandatory realmContainer using "LifecycleRealmContainer", and passing their lifecycle into it, then - the "initRealm" would be called with "onCreate"  and "closeRealm" would be called with "onDestroy".

This is done so that during their onCreate you could query the DB for initialisation. Problem is that the LifecycleEvent callback is done *after* the actual "onCreate" method is called. Therefore - the DB instances aren't initialised.

```
class ExampleActivity: AppCompatActivity(), RealmOwner {
    override val realmContainer = RealmOwner.LifecycleRealmContainer(lifecycle)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        configurationA.where<SomeRealmObject>().findAll() // object isn't initialized error
    }
}
```

The question is - is there a nice clean way for me to initialise the DB instances using the "LifecycleObserver" tool *before* the onCreate method is called in the activity/fragment I'm trying to initialise?